# create mysql user and password with random string

Tags: python, mysql

I am having a problem creating a username and password on MySQL using a random string in python. The problem is that the printed value of username and password is different from what was being created in MySQL. Can somebody explain what is happening as I am new to python and MySQL. Please sample the code below.

```py
import mysql.connector
import random
import string

def get_random_string(length):
  letters = string.ascii_letters
  result_str = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(length))
  return str(result_str)

username = get_random_string(12)
password = get_random_string(12)

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="root"
)

print(username)
print(password)

sql = 'CREATE USER "'+username+'"@"%" IDENTIFIED BY "'+password+'"';

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute(sql)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what is being printed vs. what is being stored?

Comment: @kantuni well, it has different string value. Sample is the username when printed on python is "MasfhuWCdwbW" but the created username on MySQL is "SZrWHggLtgbk"

Comment: Enable General Log temporarily and look the actual query text sent to MySQL server.

Comment: @Akina general log is on MySQL side right? Sorry as I am generally new on python and mysql. Thanks.

Comment: *general log is on MySQL side right?* True. [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  The General Query Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html). `SELECT @@general_log_file;`, save the value, `SET GLOBAL general_log_file = 'full_log_pathname';` to non-existent file, then `SET GLOBAL general_log = 1;`, execute your query, then `SET GLOBAL general_log = 0;`, restore the value for `general_log_file` and look the log file for actual query text. If your OS is Windows then use `/` in pathname instead of ```\```.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Seems that the problem lies on executing multiple statements as I am executing multiple queries with the use of multi=True. When I tried executing the statements line by line, the correct random string for username and password are now being created on mysql. Thank you very much to all.